# impossible making javascript function and new row

Tags: javascript, php, function, dynamic, addition

I'm trying to make a function that adds a row but my function on `keypress` didn't worked/. I've trying with `"`, `'`, and without which makes no difference.  When I press on the button nothing happened.

```
//function append lundi
var counterlundi= 0;
var $newRow ; 
$(function(){
    $('#add_lundi').click(function(){
        counterlundi += 1;
        $('#numlundi').append($newRow = $('<input id="numlundi' + counterlundi + '" name="numlundi[]' + '" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/> '
    )
)
```

how Do I do?

Here my php of my static input of autocomplete

```
<td>
    <b>Lundi</b> </br><?php echo $date2 ?>
    <div id="lundicon"> 
        <p id="add_lundi" class="plus"><a href="#"><span> + </span> </a></p>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="numlundi">
        <input  onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" size="10" type="text" id="projlundi" name="projlundi"onkeypress="return handleEnter2(event, this, 'task');"/>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="clientlun"> 
        <input type="text" name="clientlundi" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"  class = "client" size="12" id ="clientlundi" readonly />
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="prodesclun">
        <input type="text" name="projdesclundi" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" size="30" class "desc" id ="projdesclundi"readonly />
    </div>
</td>
```

My Javascript function of my Static input

```
//-------AUTO COMPLETE LUNDI PROJET-----
                   $("#projlundi").autocomplete({
                    source:'getautocomplete.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
function handleEnter2(e, obj, field){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    tempArrayInJS = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                    $("#clientlundi").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']);    
                    $("#projdesclundi").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['proDescription']);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","completeclient.php?q="+obj.value,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this javascript or php.. or both.?

Comment: this is a javascript function i 'll edit with more code

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Right now there is no way someone could understand what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let me explain what I think : He's trying to create an element using `PHP` which involve `javascript` function in the element using `attributes`.

Comment: If you already are using jQuery, why not use jQuery's AJAX API?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv hope that more information you have asked. Sorry if i didn't show it earlier

Comment: Where is your #add_lundi element?

Comment: @jamie something like that : i have static input ( whom i can save to  database at the end. A client have an option to add more row ( dynamic way) my static one if I press enter i can choose and opttion of autocomplete other row . I need do the same way for my dynamic one . For the moment i can show option but I can't autocomplete.


I have edited with your request morawcik.

Comment: Try: `$newRow = $('<input id="numlundi' + counterlundi + '" name="numlundi[]' + '" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/> ');   $('#numlundi').append($newRow)`

Comment: I have edited it too, which is about mainly your code formatting. You should format your code correctly (or _nearly correctly_) always.

Comment: @morawcik didn't do anything. It show option exemple if I type 07- it suggest 07-1038 but when I choose and press enter it's not complete my client and description like my static ways.

Comment: Could you check if the click function is running? (e.g. console.log('test') before counterlundi += 1; )

Comment: yeah he run cause I can make a new row I can add more input so its not the problem. and I see in the log if I add your console.log.

Comment: I'm confused. You said "When I press on the button nothing happened",  that what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain very well so I'll do my best. I make a timesheet. I have some input are there static way.( numlundi, clientlundi, prodesclun) when I type something in numlundi it suggest me some number and when I press enter its complete clientlundi and prodeslun. Now what I have a button to add dynamic input ( more row of numlundi and clientlundi) MY buttons can add my input but my new input doest have the function like my static ways. And I need like numlundi[1], numlundi[2] have the function on enter complete clientlundi[1], client[2] when I choose a autosuggest

Comment: And You can choose option in numlundi but it's not autocomplete others inputs?

Comment: my numlundi ( static) is currently work i can choose a suggest and when i press enter is complete clientlundi. I want to do the same thing with my new row I add.

Comment: Your dynamic numlundi have id numladni1, numlandi2... and if your others added inputs have that too (clientlundi1...) You need change id for inputs in handleEnter2 (like $("#clientlundi") ). First get id of used numlndi input, then remove "numlundi" from this id and add rest to  $("#clientlundi") ( $("#clientlundi"+id) )

Comment: alreayd trying nothing happen or maybe I did it like a noob when I trying to make un handleenter dynamic.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it cause I can'T make that  $newRow = $('<input id="numlundi' + counterlundi + '" name="numlundi[]' + '" onkeypress="return handleEnter2(event, this, 'task'); type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/> ');   $('#numlundi').append($newRow) Its say 'task' is error when I add \'task\' its illegale and is making a weird adding after that. So if I can'T call a function for my new row when I append I can't even make a function for autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#numlundi').on('keypress', 'input', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                tempArrayInJS = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                if ($this.attr('id') != 'numlundi') {
                    var id = $this.attr('id').replace('numlundi', '');
                    $("#clientlundi"+id).val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']);    
                    $("#projdesclundi"+id).val( tempArrayInJS[0]['proDescription']);
                } else {
                    $("#clientlundi").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']);    
                    $("#projdesclundi").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['proDescription']);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","completeclient.php?q="+$this.val(),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
})
```

Comment: I solved 3/4 of the problem with this :   
  
`code
     $newRow = $('<input id="numlundi' + counterlundi + '" name="numlundi[]' + '" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/> ');   $('#numlundi').append($newRow)
      $newRow.keypress (function (e) { return handledyn(event, this, 'task');}) 
`
so I increment each time my counterlundi but if I make 5 row I can't modify after that my first row.

Comment: check now (second ) on the end "if ($(this).attr('id') != 'numlundi')) {" )

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Could you check: console.log($(this)) before: var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('numlundi', '');

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest, jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]
 connection.php:158
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Works well but one more thing exemple : I add 1 row its work its complete. I add a second row its work well too its complete . BUT If I return on the first row added I edit and press enter its actually edition the last row I added.

Comment: Could you change: if ($this.attr('id') != 'numlundi') { to: if ($this.attr('id') != 'projlundi') {

Comment: I've changed but nothing change for the last bug. I mentionned if I edit a row after I append a new one.

Comment: After var $this = $(this); check $this.attr('id') with log (on edit first, second and back first again)

Comment: Sorry I did'nt understand what should I do with the log?

Comment: put: console.log($this.attr('id')) after var $this = $(this); then autocomplete for first input and check log, autocomplete for second input and check log and back to first input)